# Stacked bar plot of boolean Pandas column: Why does it take forever?

Tags: pandas, time, anaconda, boolean, bar-chart

I have boolean column in pandas dataframe in Spyder 3.7 in Anaconda 1.9.7

```
df['is_in_europe'].unique()      
Out[5]: array([False,  True])
```

and want to create a horizontal stacked bar chart of the distribution of 'True' and 'False'

```
df['is_in_europe'].astype(float).plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

However, this code takes forever to execute. Any ideas why?

Comment: What is your definition of forever? How many data points?

Comment: 250k. I left it for half an hour and then ran out of patience. However, I have been creating similar bar graphs with the same data which took seconds to create which is why I started thinking that there is a problem. And actually, after inserting the value_counts() function it worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure what the underlying issue with the code above is but inserting `value_counts()` function helped me get the graph

```
df['is_in_europe'].astype(float).value_counts().plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
```